# How to create an executable file having input file and output file as parameters?

Tags: c#, console-application

Okay I have looked at a lot of sources but I cannot seem to find the answer. I have an assignment where I will a parameter for an input file path and a parameter for an output file path using a C# console application. My question is where can I find an example which shows the code to set parameters like that.
Thank you.

Comment: The key point is 'command line parameters' are just strings which the operating system breaks up into an array and passes on to your program. The user can type in anything they like and you have to make sense of their input as best you can for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

They're just command line arguments, right? For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Foo <input file> <output file>");
            return 1; // Indicate failure
        }
        string inputFile = args[0];
        string outputFile = args[1];
        // Use inputFile and outputFile...

        return 0; // Indicate success
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for. In msdn, it only talks about specific inputs as parameters but not for files

Comment: @user1255009: The command line arguments are just strings. How you *use* them is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these links (include references, source code, sanples and explanations):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28VS.71%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check for documentation on [Main method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) in msdn